# Rate of change in temperature as a bug moves.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

My question comes from a problem from a multivariable calculus class. The problem states

1
.
The temperature on a hot surface is given by
$T=100e^{−(x^2+y^2)}$. A bug follows the trajectory
$r(t) =<t\cos(2t), t\sin(2t)>$
.
What
is
the
rate
that
temperature
is
changing
as
the
bug
moves?

using the chain rule in respects to $\frac {dT}{dt}$ then substituting t for x and y I get
$-200t\cos(2t)e^{-((t\cos(2t))^2+(t\sin(2t)^2)}(\cos(2t)-2t\sin(2t))-200t\sin(2t)e^{-((t\cos(2t))^2+(t\sin(2t)^2)}(\sin(2t)+2t\cos(2t)$

but it is not clear how to reduce to the answer:
 $-200te^{-t^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in your computation. An approach could be to write
$$
\frac {dT}{dt}=\frac {\partial x}{\partial t}\frac {\partial T}{\partial x}+\frac {\partial y}{\partial t}\frac {\partial T}{\partial y} \tag1
$$ with
$$
\frac {\partial x}{\partial t}=\cos(2t)-2t\sin(2t), \quad \frac {\partial y}{\partial t}=\sin(2t)+2t\cos(2t) \tag2
$$ and
$$
\frac {\partial T}{\partial x}=-2x\:T, \quad \frac {\partial T}{\partial y}=-2y\:T \tag3
$$ then plugging $(2)$ and $(3)$ in $(1)$, you get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac {dT}{dt}&=(\cos(2t)-2t\sin(2t))(-2x\:T)+(\sin(2t)+2t\cos(2t))(-2y\:T)\\\\
&=(\cos(2t)-2t\sin(2t))(-2t\cos(2t)\:T)+(\sin(2t)+2t\cos(2t))(-2t\sin(2t)\:T)\\\\
&=[(\cos(2t)-2t\sin(2t))\cos(2t)+(\sin(2t)+2t\cos(2t))\sin(2t)](-2t\:T)\\\\
&=[(\cos^2(2t)+\sin^2(2t))-2t\sin(2t)\cos(2t)+2t\cos(2t)\sin(2t)](-2t\:T)\\\\
&=-2t\:T\\\\
&=-200te^{-t^2}
\end{align}
$$
giving the desired result.

Comment: I am not seeing how you are getting $\frac{∂T}{∂x}$ and $\frac{∂T}{∂y}$

Comment: Recall that $(e^{-u(x)})'=u'(x)e^{-u(x)}$, here $u(x)=-x^2$, thus $100(e^{-x^2-y^2})'_x=100(-2x)e^{-x^2-y^2}=-2xT$, regardless to $y$.

Comment: Ah I see what I did now, you have $T$ on the right side as well.

Comment: As I do like your answer, I am still unable to get to the answer with it. we have $(\cos(2t) - 2t\sin(2t))(-2xT) - (\sin(2t)+2t\cos(2t))(-2yT)$ once I substitute T for the equation it starts looking like where I originally got stuck.

Comment: Ok, I will provide some details in my answer:)

Comment: Yes I see it, it all comes down to a bit of diligence. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We have: $T(x(t),y(t)) = 100e^{-t^2} \to T'(t) = -200te^{-t^2}$

Comment: This is comes to the right answer, but from your answer, I don't see why in general, when I have multiple variables that can be parametrized with one I can differentiate without first differentiating the multiple variables. Is this to say, that I can always substitute t for x and y and I don't have to worry about taking the partial derivatives of x and y? Perhaps I am just not understanding something fundamental about the chain rule.

Comment: To make sense of things - So because we are measuring the rate of change in temperature, we only need to find out $t$ to respects of $T$. But we only know t through functions x and y or  the bugs movement vector.So by simply substituting t for x and y we  can differentiate become we are not worried about the change of x and y.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.....

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The key is to use $\sin^2(2t)+\cos^2(2t)=1$.

So, simplify first the exponential term, factor it and expand the remaining. You will arrive to the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

So the temperature at a point $(x, y)$ is $T(x, y) = 100 e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}$. Your path $r$ is parametrised by $t$ in that

$x(t) = t \cos(2t)$

and

$y(t) = t \sin(2t)$

so we can find the temerpature along the path $r$ just by

$T(x(t), y(t)) = 100 e^{-(t^2 \cos^2(2t) + t^2 \sin^2(2t))} = 100 e^{-t^2}$,

since $\cos^2 + \sin^2 = 1$.

Note now the temperature along the path only depends on $t$, so we can differentiate:

$\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{\mathrm{d}t} = 100e^{-t^2} \times (-2t) = -200 e^{-t^2}$,

by an appliaction of the chain rule.